# AppleScript (or other code?) to change iTunes library depending on disk presence

Tags: macos, itunes, external, drive

I have my large music library on my external drive, and a more portable sized library on my internal drive. What I really would like to have is an app that checks for the presence of my external drive and then proceeds to launch iTunes with the correct library.

I am aware of the [question here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693780/applescript-to-launch-itunes-with-a-specific-library) and while that may be pretty close to what I want to do, I do not know enough Applescript to make it happen. [There is also this neat script](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050123205848370) , but it gives me this error: "Finder got an error: ln: /Users/Matt/Music/: Permission denied" and I don't know how to change permissions for that to work. Plus I don't need it to function for every user, although it isn't a big deal.

[There is another guy](http://www.stalecoffee.com/2012/12/managing-and-switching-itunes-libraries-from-alac-to-match/) who got his situation resolved with ControPlane, which I currently use for other purposes. I could not figure out a sensible way to run the script only when I launch iTunes and still have it switch my Network prefs for when I'm at work or home. 
Would changing one of those Applescripts work best? If so, how can I make it work? Or could we have ControlPlane run a script changing which library iTunes will open, depending on if my drive is connected or not? (While still maintaining my correct network settings)...

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution you might try is using [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/6265/keyboard-maestro). You would be able to build a trigger for iTunes, so that launching the application would run a script, and that script could choose the appropriate library based on the presence of the external drive.