# Script to search and compare 2 itunes libraries (python or applescript)

Tags: python, macos, applescript, itunes

I have 2 itunes libraries. One old one and one new. There are duplicate tracks, so I want to write a script either in Python (I assume with the XML can be useful or maybe there is a python addition I can use) or Apple script. The flow Would be:

Human give me the location of your Library A:
Human points and hits OK
Human give me location of Library B:
Human points and hits OK

For every track in B, see if exist in A
If true
Change comment Tag to "dup already in A"
If false
do nothing

Can anyone help?

Comment: There are some tools in the `os` module that should be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are processing speed and memory issues? If they are, then I would suggest using Python. Although you'll probably have to find a third party module, it should run a lot faster. That being said, Applescript will give you the far easier solution. You could gather some key information about each track of one of the libraries (the one already loaded into iTunes) into an array with something like this:

```
set the_tracks to {}
tell application "iTunes"
    repeat with t in (tracks of user playlist "Music")
    set end of the_tracks to {name of t, artist of t, album of t, time of t}
    end repeat
end tell
```

Then, using the handy code from this other Stack Overflow question ([Applescript to launch iTunes with a specific library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693780/applescript-to-launch-itunes-with-a-specific-library?rq=1)), quit iTunes and reboot it with the second library. Then iterate over the tracks again, but this time instead of tossing them into an array, check if the key information matches up. If it doesn't, keep iterating, if it does, simply use the code:

```
set comment of t to "Dup already in A"
```