# Launching Apple Music with a specific library using Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript, apple-music

I'd like to have an Applescript change the current Apple Music library automatically, instead of requiring me to hold down the option key when opening the app and manually select a new one. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1693973/10844931) answer which apparently works for iTunes, but the the name of the library location default seems to be different in Apple Music, and I can't figure out what it is. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming that you ever find the library files, what happens if you launch by double-clicking the desired library file? Does the app open with that as the active library? As to finding the correct folder… is there a 'Music' folder in the user Library? Also, try exporting the library somewhere and then using the filename to search for any similarly named files.

Comment: When I click the desired library file, Apple Music does open, but it just opens to the previous library, not necessarily the one that was clicked. As for your other question, I'm not really looking for the folder, more so just the name of the default to use when `defaults read com.apple.music '[default name]' | pbcopy` is executed (see the answer I linked in my question if you're not quite sure what I mean). For iTunes, it was 'book:1:iTunes Library Location', but I can't figure out what it is for Apple Music.

Comment: Funny but I get nothing when I try that approach… neither 'book' nor 'alis'. The only 'library' I get is the default library folder. Perhaps it's related to my running Sierra, or perhaps that I have but one library. Hope find a solution.